# How to properly left-right justify text

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, justification

As you can see in the image below some of text falls into the margin for some reason i am using `\RequirePackage[none]{hyphenat}` this package to prevent hyphenation and i assume this must be causing the issue. How can I solve this, thanks!

[image]

Comment: What happens when you issue `\AtBeginDocument{\sloppy}` in your premble?

Comment: What’s the reason for disabling hyphenation?

Comment: if you disable hyphenation you can not expect to justify text in any reasonable way, you would be better to set `\raggedright`

Comment: You ask, "How can I solve this"? Easy: Don't load the `hyphenat` package.

Comment: tex prevents the inter-word spacing from stretching too much (`\sloppy` as in the first comment allows more stretch)  but having large spaces makes the text very hard to read so the reasonable approaches are to allow hyphenation, or to use raggedright so allowing inter-word spacing to be constant with the extra space being at the end of each line not between the words.